# how to use .htaccess to rewrite rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am working on a project which required SEO, for SEO its needed user-friendly URLs, i want to make my url look user-friendly, this is my .htaccess code i want to make my url look like:

```
http://localhost/footboleh/article/Some-text
```

while curruntly its look like:

```
http://localhost/footboleh/article?url=Some-text
```

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i had try some rewrite rules which are

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

its bring me index page without css and js and giving error in console 
console error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and i had print_r ($_GET] its shows:

> Array ( [url] => article/some-text.php )

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude your css and js files from the rewrite, usually via:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

just before your rewriterule line.

Comment: So your css/js is still not appearing? Post what your htaccess looks like now.

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Looks right. Does your css/js load if you visit it directly in the browser?

Comment: No, if you have the htaccess file there, what happens if you try to  visit yoursite.com/yourcssfile.css? Do you see your css file printed out?

Comment: yes buddy its showing all js function and css classes

Comment: So what is the issue with the main page now, if the css/js is working now?

Comment: i found the actual issue in my article page the link for resources are like **http://localhost/footboleh/article/assets/css/animate.min.css** but it should look like **http://localhost/footboleh/assets/css/animate.min.css**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172768/discussion-between-sam-and-cometfish).

Comment: Right, so you need to either add "../" in front of those css/js paths, or add "/footboleh/" (with first slash to make it from the root of the site), or set base href of the page to "localhost/footboleh/"